# MPI receive and send functions blocking each other?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Let's say i have a MPI process_0 waiting for messages from two different processess (process_1 and process_2). Something like this:

```
...
MPI_Recv(&message_1, 1, MPI_INT, process_1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Recv(&message_2, 1, MPI_INT, process_2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
...
```

Imagine the scenario where when process_2 sends it's message, to process_0, before process_1. What happens then?

I guess process_0 must recieve the message from process_1 before it can read the message from process_2?

What happens att the send function at process_2? Will it be stuck at the send function trying to deliver the message until process_0 can receive it? Or will it send the message not caring if process_0 has received it or not and continue running the consecutive code after the send function?

Comment: _What happens at the send function at process_2?_ That very much depends on the way how P2 sends this message. There are _blocking_ vs _nonblocking_ send operations each in 4 different communication _modes_ (standard, buffered, synchronous, and ready).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MPI standard, a correct program should always assume a blocking send (e.g. `MPI_Send()`) will block until a matching receive is posted.

Note that if the message is short enough (depending on your MPI implementation, your interconnect and other factors), it might be sent in eager mode and `MPI_Send()` will return immediately. If your MPI implementation features a progress thread, `MPI_Send()` might also return before a matching receive is posted. That being said, you should not assume this is a behavior mandated by the standard, and if you want to write portable code, you should assume `MPI_Send()` will always block until a matching receive is posted.